# Draftjs - How to add a simple youtube video embed to Draftjs?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

There are a couple of plugins for this but last updated 4 years ago and full of bugs and crashes without any responses to issues.

Is there a simple way to add an option to embed a youtube video using draftjs in a react component?